# "Asked my height" or "asked of my height"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

"Asked my height" sounds strange, while "asked of my height" sounds like an overkill. "Asked what my height was" sounds terrible.

Comment: "Asked my height" seems fine to me, or "asked for my height"; definitely not "asked of my height".

Comment: It may sound strange, and seems to mess up categorisations of sentences (John asked me / John asked my age), but 'I was asked my age' and 'John asked me my height' etc are quite idiomatic.

Comment: It really depends on the specific thing being queried. At one end of the spectrum are words like *height, age*. Personally, I'd place *nationality, preference* somewhere in the middle. At the other end are things like *health* (I'm not sure anyone would say *"He asked my health"*, for example).

Comment: ... But they might drink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Asked my height" sounds perfectly fine, and it's more concise than "Asked what my height was".